# How to catch unexpected messages in c#, while I send messages and I also want to accept answers for the messages?

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have an app, what have a few methods. They're basically button click events and timer events. When I click on a button or a few seconds passed, the timer or the button sends a message (I think TCP message) and instantly wait for an answer from another app. I use `StreamWriter.Write()` and `StreamReader.Read()` for the messages and answers. (They creates and accepts TCP string messages, I think).

But there are also unexpected messages, what can arrive anytime to my app. I don't know how to receive them.

Idea 1: after every `StreamReader.Read()`, prepare for the case when an unexpected message can come. But it seems to be a bad idea. Although the sending and reading messages happens very often, modifying the code in every place seems to be a bit weird solution.

Idea 2: using of a thread. It would accept every incoming message with `StreamReader.Read()`. But in my main thread, I would need to remove the `StreamReader.Read()` methods and simply wait for the answers from the other thread. This would happen with while(I don't get the answer){}, and this also seems to be a bad solution.

Idea 3: Using an eventhandler? I have never used any for this, so I'm a bit confused about how to use events for this task.

Any other idea?

Comment: Where are the messages coming from? Same app? Other app? Thougth about using a message framework?

Comment: Other app. And the messages are TCP messages, I think. (strings)

Comment: TCP doesn't do messages. It does an endless stream of bytes in both directions. If you want messages, it's up to *you* to implement those atop TCP or use a higher-level protocol that does do messages. Since at the moment you're talking about something that doesn't exist (TCP messages), it's very unclear what you're looking for.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I create a TCPClient and I create a NetworkStream from that. Then I give the NetworkStream variable to the StreamReader and StreamWriter instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your app allowed to read answer after a delay ? If I got it well, your app can send messages to something with button and can receive messages from it, sometimes from that request, sometimes spontaneously.

The immediate thing, maybe not the best, which comes to my mind is a polling peek thread.

Create a thread which loop until a condition is met (like shutting down communication), and which raise events, and wait for acknowledge

```
while(active){
  if(yourStreamReader.Peek()>0) { //Blocking until data received
    MyNewDataEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); //Event raising
    Acknowledge.WaitOne(); //Wait an acknowledge
  }
}
```

And use a Callback on this raised event.

```
event EventHandler MyNewDataEvent;
ManualResetEvent Acknowledge;
//...
//...
MyNewDataEvent += OnNewData;
Acknowledge = new ManualResetEvent();
//...
//...
void OnNewData(object sender, EventArgs e){
  //Read the messages, do stuff
  Acknowledge.Set(); //When done with StreamReader
}
```

The cool effect is that it's also working for the answers from the button-sent requests, so you don't even have to read immediately the answer. That would be a good exercise to learn about event and eventhandler, which are, to me, REALLY useful ! Warning : Be careful that only one thread/callback use the streamreader at once.

Comment: MyNewDataEvent?.Invoke(this, e); //Event raising

What will be the "e"? How will the thread get that?

Comment: e are the events arguments, which is part of the signature of default EventHandler. Here the program make no use of it, the only important point is that upon MyNewDataEvent being raised, the method OnNewData will be called. I edited the program to reflect the fact you do not need any event argument by using EventArgs.Empty, which I should have done in the first place. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: okay, I wrote MyNewDataEvent?.Invoke(this, null); 
It has a problem with the dot. What to do with this?

Comment: What's the error message ? Also I didn't add any access keyword, if you're accessing the event out of declaration scope, make it public. Make sure the event is declared in your class scope, not in a function.

Comment: The problem is with the question mark. Monodevelop doesn't understand that, I think. But the app is needs to be written on Raspbian.

Comment: The question mark is the Safe Navigation Operator, which, here, check if MyNewDataEvent is null before trying to Invoke it. It has been added with C# 6.0, and it's possible that your Mono version is old enough not to have it. Just remove it. If you want to keep it safe, check if MyNewDataEvent is null and, if not, invoke the event

Comment: Okay, I have implemented this and accepting messages works. But in my code I send the message and I don't get suddenly the answer, because obviously my app prints the empty message, what I didn't get yet. 
How should I do this without "while the last character is not >"? I think that would be a bad idea.

Comment: Okay, I accept this and I ask another question based on this.